# Какое регулярное выражение использовать для MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Есть таблица wp_posts, в ней есть колонка post_contetnt.
Почти в каждой ячейке есть текст который нужно удлать:

купить за 716 рублей.

716 - динамично, везде по разному.

В идеале отсекать все от "купить за" и до точки "."

Какая регулярка, да и вообще сам SQL запрос решит эту задачу.

Comment: Эта задача не решается в ряде случаев на MySQL.
Если у вас UTF-8 кодировка - решайте не на стороне MySQL. RegExp в MySQL Достаточно беден и не предназначен для таких задач.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков, начиная с mysql-8.0.4 (и с какой-то уже старой версии MariaDB) с юникодом всё должно быть нормально...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, MySQL до версии 5.7 подвержен, дальше - не в курсе. В любом случае, мое мнение не меняется даже для последних версий, регэксп не для этого, выбрать строки по совпадению с регэкспом, но никак не удалить **часть** строки..